# Glide doesn't recognize the rotation of the camera

Tags: android, camera, android-glide

I need to load an image from camera on Android. I use this code to open camera:

```
 private void openCamera()
{
    mMediaUri =getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    photoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
    startActivityForResult(photoIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

}

private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaTypeImage)
{
    //check for external storage
    if(isExternalStorageAvaiable())
    {
        File mediaStorageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        String fileName = "";
        String fileType = "";
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new java.util.Date());

        fileName = "IMG_"+timeStamp;
        fileType = ".jpg";

        File mediaFile;
        try
        {
            mediaFile = File.createTempFile(fileName,fileType,mediaStorageDir);
            absolutePath = mediaFile.getAbsolutePath();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("St","Error creating file: " + mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() +fileName +fileType);
            return null;
        }
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", mediaFile);
    }
    //something went wrong
    return null;

}

private boolean isExternalStorageAvaiable()
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}
```

and this is the check in `onActivityResult()`:

```
 else if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) //dalla fotocamera
        {

            if (data != null)  //caso galleria
            {
                mMediaUri = data.getData();
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(mMediaUri).centerCrop().into(photo);
            }
            else
            {

                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .load(mMediaUri)
                        .bitmapTransform(new CenterCrop(getActivity()), new RoundedCornersTransformation(getActivity(), 15, 2))
                        .into(photo);

            }


        }
```

the problem is that in some devices (like Galaxy S4 with Nougat installed) Glide loads image 90 degree right instead of loads image correctly. I've read that Glide manages `ExifInterface`by default, but in this case it doesn't work.
I have only this problem when I load with camera: with gallery or byte array it loads all in the correct mode.

There is a way to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: `data.getData()` will return `null` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` on millions of devices, as `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not supposed to return a `Uri`. You already know where the picture is (`mediaFile`), so use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem, are this two lines:

```
    fileName = "IMG_"+timeStamp;
    fileType = ".jpg";
```

using Bitmap instead of Jpeg solve the problem:

```
fileName = "IMG_"+timeStamp;
fileType = ".bmp";
```